# Hash-table - Array of Linked-list - C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, hashtable

I'm trying to create a Hash-table by using an array on linked-nodes (making a linked list).
But I'm having difficulties inserting a value into the Hash-table. When I run it, I get this:

http://gyazo.com/3a28a70e66b3ea34e08223e5948f49c0.png

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
  int num;
  Node * next;
};

class intHashTable {
private:
  int size;
  Node ** table;
public:
  intHashTable(int size);  // construct a new hash table with size elements
  ~intHashTable();     // delete the memory for all internal components
  void insert(int num);    // insert num into the hash table, no effect
               // if num is already in table
  void remove(int num);    // remove num from the hash table, no effect if not in table
  int lookup(int num);     // return 1 if num is already in table, 0 otherwise
  void print(void);        // print the elements of the hash table to the screen
};

// construct a new hash table with nelements elements
intHashTable::intHashTable(int nelements)
{
  size = nelements;
  table = new Node*[size];
  for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    table[i] = NULL;
  }
}

intHashTable::~intHashTable()
{
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
   {
      Node* temp = table[i];
      while(temp != NULL)
      {
         Node* next = temp->next;
         delete temp;
         temp = next;
      }
   }
   size = 0;
   delete[] table;
}

void intHashTable::insert(int num){
    int location = ((unsigned)num) % size;
    Node *runner = table[location];
    if(runner == NULL ){
    runner->num = num;
     }else{
        while(runner != NULL ){
            runner = runner->next;
        }
        runner->num = num;
    }
   }

int main(){
    intHashTable a (10);
    a.insert(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a debugger in Code::Blocks? it will tell you what's wrong...

Comment: There are no errors or warnings.

Comment: In insert, runner = table[location] is basically NULL, isn't it?

Comment: When you run in a debugger there are no errors or warnings or handy stack traces?

Comment: No I didnt run the debugger. I just compiled.

Comment: if(runner == NULL ){
    runner->num = num;
     }

Comment: @Caribou That's what I'm doing.

Comment: Yes - runner (a NULL variable) is used to access a member on runner - runner must be initialised to access a member right? (runner = new Whatever();)

Comment: 1 piece of friendly :) advice - using a debugger will give you an edge over other students that don't - it is something I always ask about at interview.

Comment: Also, your name is in the screenshot, if that bothers you, ayokunle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the logic here is wrong

```
int location = ((unsigned)num) % size;
Node *runner = table[location];

if(runner == NULL ) // if null u dereference it!
{
 runner->num = num;
}
else
{
  while(runner != NULL ) {  // u loop until null
    runner = runner->next;
  }
  runner->num = num;  // once u reach null u dereference it!
}
```

i would suggest instead:

first a `ctor` for your Node

```
class Node {
public:
  int num;
  Node * next;

  Node( int _n ) : num(_n), next(NULL) { } 
};
```

and then

```
if ( runner != NULL )
{
   while ( runner->next != NULL )
   {
      runner = runner->next;
   }
   runner->next = new Node( num );
}
else
{
  table[location] = new Node( num ); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After construction of `intHashTable`, all the elements of `table` are still `NULL`. However, in the function `insert`, one element is dereferenced:

```
Node *runner = table[location];
runner = runner->next;
```

This makes the program crash, because [it is illegal to dereference a null pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/418/).

Comment: and if(runner == NULL ){
    runner->num = num;
     }

Comment: @Caribou best test case ever

Comment: @user1965283: not really – now it will crash on the line pointed out by Caribou.

Comment: @Caribou   Node *runner = table[location];
    runner = new Node();
    if(runner == NULL ){
        runner->num = num;
    } Still giving an error.

Comment: After runner = new Node(), runner will never be NULL.

Comment: @Caribou I got it, I think. Lol.

Comment: @user1965283 Pukku deserves the thanks - he saw the issue before me

Answer (score 1):

This code certainly won't work:

```
if(runner == NULL ){
runner->num = num;
```

If runner is NULL, then you should never dereference it (using * or -> on it).

Answer (score 1):

```
Node *runner = table[location];
runner = runner->next;
if(runner == NULL )
```

You never verified whether `table[location]` is null. But during construction of your hashtable, there are no nodes inside the node table (you set yourself every entry to null).

The problem with your code is that you never think about allocating your node. You should be doing

```
Node* toInsert = new Node;
toInsert->next= NULL;
toInsert->num = num;

if(table[location]==NULL){
   table[location] = toInsert;  
}
else{
    Node *runner = table[location];
    while(runner->next != NULL){
         runner = runner->next;
    }
    runner->next = toInsert;
}
```